# Loading RDF files using TDB

Tags: java, rdf, jena, triplestore, tdb

I'm using **Apache Jena TDB** to load many files for future reference, when I load using the `getDefaultModel` method (default model), everything happens normally, but when I try to use a named model the process gets very slow and the CPU reaches 100%, sometimes memory overflow occurs.

Can anyone tell me the difference between the default model and the named model?

I can not understand the difference and I think they should have the same behavior.

```
model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
TDBLoader.loadModel(model, file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Vs

```
public static final String ALL_STORAGE = "http://instance/allstorage";
model = dataset.getNamedModel(ALL_STORAGE) ;
TDBLoader.loadModel(model, file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Please ask this on the Jena mailing list, this is much more appropriate than StackOverflow. And don't forget to add more details. What's `dataset`, how large, how much memory do you assign, why do you use namedModel etc. And clearly, loading named graphs can be a difference depending on what `dataset` contains.

Comment: "the CPU reaches 100%, sometimes memory overflow occurs." -- suggestive that the heap isn't quite big enough and is close to exhaustion causing the GC to run excessively.